# Development Server Load Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I wasn't able to load my app engine development server due to an error without a log file. After re-installing it and deleting the .ini files, I got the launcher to launch.

However, one out of my three projects will now not launch, with a trace that doesn't make much sense (it refers to pickle when I don't use it anywhere in my project). If you can give me any help it would be appreciated.

Trace:

```
2016-05-15 22:45:02 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=4712', '--admin_port=8000', 'C:\\Users\\Paul\\Desktop\\Tram Live\\App Engine\\Sheffield']"
INFO     2016-05-15 22:45:05,448 devappserver2.py:769] Skipping SDK update check.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 84, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 80, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 1040, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 1033, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 820, in start
    request_data, storage_path, options, configuration)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 925, in _create_api_server
    appidentity_oauth_url=options.appidentity_oauth_url)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\api_server.py", line 477, in setup_stubs
    simple_search_stub.SearchServiceStub(index_file=search_index_path))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\simple_search_stub.py", line 683, in __init__
    self.Read()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\simple_search_stub.py", line 1164, in Read
    read_indexes = self._ReadFromFile()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\simple_search_stub.py", line 1138, in _ReadFromFile
    version, indexes = pickle.load(open(self.__index_file, 'rb'))
EOFError
2016-05-15 22:45:05 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Comment: Looks like your app's search indexes file may be corrupted. I'm not sure exactly which is that file on Windows, but you can temporarily hack `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\simple_search_stub.py` to print/display that `self.__index_file`. Then try to rename that file, I *think* it should be re-created automatically.

Comment: Thanks - I managed to find the location of the datastore and delete it, which forced it to rebuild everything.

Comment: So it's working now?